# browserFIeld never release its focus in blackberry os5?

Tags: blackberry

This is may be old question but i dont get proper solution
if it is wrong please ignore otherwise please halp me

I have one main screen with two verticleManagers

1)For browserField
2)one button

first i add successfully My Browserfield to First verticlemanger and also add button to second verticlemanager

finally two verticlemanager added to main screen.

in OS6 i dont get any problem it works fine

but in OS5 i got problem that is

> once the Browserfield is getting focus, it never release its focus so i am unable to navigate downside of the Browserfield. Means i am unable to click on blackberry advertisement Banner.i am unable to navigate down from browserfield using trackpad

this is my sample code

```
class browserScreen extends MainScreen
{
    String url;
    BrowserField browserField;
    public browserScreen() {
        VerticalFieldManager main_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            }
        };

        VerticalFieldManager browserfield_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight()-50);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight()-50);
            }
        };
        url="http://www.google.com";
        BrowserFieldConfig browserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR,Boolean.TRUE);
         browserField=new BrowserField(browserFieldConfig);
         browserField.requestContent(url);
         browserfield_mgr.add(browserField);
        main_mgr.add(browserfield_mgr);
        VerticalFieldManager button_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),50);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),50);
            }
        };
        button_mgr.add(new SeparatorField());
        ButtonField btn=new ButtonField("BUTTON MANAGER");
        button_mgr.add(btn);
        main_mgr.add(button_mgr);
        add(main_mgr);

    }
}
```

any help can be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i googled a lot i conclude that This is OS 5 issue. it wont resolve it in OS5. It resolved In OS6. You have to provide a way to move the focus off the BrowserField yourself.  I have tried a variety of mechanisms to do this, like detecting Escape in the Screen's keyChar method, the best I have found so far is to use the Menu and give the users the option of swapping focus out of the BrowserField.  In general I do not recommend sharing the Screen between a Web Field and any other.

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{
    VerticalFieldManager vertical;
    HorizontalFieldManager hor;
    String url;
    BrowserField browserField;
    Banner bannerAd ;
    private static boolean flag=false;
    public LoadingScreen() 
    {   
//      

    VerticalFieldManager Veret=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL){
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
        }
    };
    //Veret.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK));
        VerticalFieldManager main_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight()-50);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight()-50);
            }
        };

        url="http://www.google.com";
        BrowserFieldConfig browserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR,Boolean.TRUE);
         browserField=new BrowserField(browserFieldConfig);
         browserField.requestContent(url);

         main_mgr.add(browserField);
         Veret.add(main_mgr);

         final Bitmap ad_bg=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("add_bg.png");
         VerticalFieldManager add_back=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH|Field.FOCUSABLE){
             protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, ad_bg.getWidth(), ad_bg.getHeight(), ad_bg, 0, 0);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
             protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(ad_bg.getWidth(), ad_bg.getHeight());
                setExtent(ad_bg.getWidth(), ad_bg.getHeight());
            }
         };
         try{
               Bitmap customPlaceholder = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("add_bg.png");
               bannerAd = new Banner(31848, null, 100000, customPlaceholder); 
               bannerAd.setBorderColor(Color.RED);
               int i=(Display.getWidth()-320)/2;
               bannerAd.setPadding(0, 0, 0, i);
               bannerAd.setBannerTransitionColor(Color.RED);
               bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE); 
              // Dialog.inform(""+bannerAd.getMMASize());

           }catch (Exception e) {
               Dialog.inform(e.getMessage());
        }
        add_back.add(bannerAd);
        Veret.add(add_back);
           add(Veret);

    }
    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) 
       { 

        int i=Integer.parseInt(StartUp.getOsVersion().substring(0, 1));
            if(i<6)
            menu.add(_testItem);
       }

     private MenuItem _testItem = new MenuItem("Go to Advertise", 100, 9)
        {
                public void run(){

                    bannerAd.setFocus();

                 }
        };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in OS5. Its been fixed in os6 and upwards . These are the reasons why you are seeing the strange behaviour. You cannot get the same behaviour in os5. The only thing you could do is a hack, which is to setfocus on the `button_mgr` . The code will look like this.

```
   // override the invokeAction method
    public boolean invokeAction(int action) {
            Field f = getFieldWithFocus();
            // check the type of field you are looking for , 
            //here i am checking if its a verticalfieldmanager
            if (f instanceof VerticalFieldManager) { 
                    button_mgr.setFocus();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.invokeAction(action);
    }
```

this will setfocus on your button.

Comment: sorry i already try this but i dont understand one thing that when invokeAction method will call can you please intigrate your solution with my above code and check it please

Comment: What did you try? what happened then? did you check http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#invokeAction(int) .It tells what invokeaction is